# How to get selected multiple checked value into array of object

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have some checkboxes which comes from loop,I need to capture selected/preselected  values on click submit into below format 
.

```
[
  { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
  { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] },
  { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"] }
];
```

I am already getting those values but after on check and click submit button,but here I need is to get value for already checked on submit button. Here is the code below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9fmyz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
      <ul *ngFor="let item of nestedjson">
        <li class="parentNav">{{item.name}}</li>
        <li class="childData">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of item.value; let i = index">{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" (change)="item.checked[i] = !item.checked[i]" checked ></span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div><button type="submit" (click)="getit()">submit</button></div>
    </div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
      })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
        data:any;
        nestedjson:any;
        message = '';
        test:any;
     constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
         }

      ngOnInit() {
         this.nestedjson = [
        { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
        { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] },
        { name: "parent3", value: ["child3"] }
      ];

      this.nestedjson.forEach(v => v.checked = Array(v.value.length).fill(false));
    } 

    getit(){
        const data = this.nestedjson;
        let duplicatePushArray = this.nestedjson.reduce((acc, v) => {
          let temp = {name: v.name, value: []};
          v.checked.forEach((val, i) => {
            if(val){
                temp.value.push(v.value[i]);
            }
          })
          if(temp.value.length > 0){
                acc.push(temp)
          }
          return acc
        }, []);

    console.log('Final Array: ', duplicatePushArray)
   /*output: [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}]*/
    }
    }
```

Comment: There is FormArrays for that. Check this sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example

Comment: Can't we fix with existing code,if I use reactive form I need to change  whole code.Already my code is working but with on check the checkbox.If its preselected its showing empty value

Comment: Can you show how preselection is occuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bc8m6q?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
  getit() {
    var duplicatePushArray = [];

    this.nestedjson.forEach(item => {
      console.log(item);
      let checked = [];
      item.checked.forEach((isCkecked, i) => {
        if (isCkecked) {
          checked.push(item.value[i]);
        }
      });
      if (checked.length > 0) {
        duplicatePushArray.push({
          name: item.name,
          value: checked
        });
      }
    });
    console.log("Final Array: ", duplicatePushArray);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer here for pre selected checkbox value is coming empty array    I tried for this code  <li *ngFor="let child of item.value; let i = index">{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" checked (change)="item.checked[i] = !item.checked[i]"></span></li>  , Also  if I wont select  any child that parent also should not come here

Comment: I mean just I need the same output which comes earlier on submit for pre selected checkbox,I dont need to capture value on check,I need to capture on submit for selected checkbox

Comment: I am using checked in html

Comment: I have edited in this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkmpwy

Comment: Try this:  this.nestedjson.forEach(v => v.checked = Array(v.value.length).fill(true));

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g1vk4n?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,One small modification ,For example suppose I have not selected child3 checkbox that object itself  should not come there,

Comment: Can you please help me on it

Comment: I will add it in 2 hours

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER Check the modified answer

Comment: If I used same logic for radio box , but selection object is not coming properly inside the array <li *ngFor="let child of item.value; let i = index">{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input  type="radio" value="{{child}}" name="{{item.name}}" (change)="item.checked[i] = !item.checked[i]" ></span></li>

Comment: It is not working if I remove checked from html,array is coming blank. actually in my project I have 2 div one is preselected other is manual select and then submit. Here main requirement is to capture value of checkboxes and radio boxes on submit. Can you please modify it